# HOWTO: Long ListView wirh thumbnail delay loading?

Tags: jquery, mobile, lazy-loading, thumbnails

I need a help.
I have a long ListView with thumbnail icons.
Like this - http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/lists/lists-thumbnails.html

How do I tweak the system so the, at 1st only the items which are being shown on the screen, those thumbnail will be loaded. Then if the user scrolls down, more thumbnail images will be loaded.
that is as the user scrolls down, the images will be loaded.

Same thing happens in Facebook Timeline. Try to see the old posts....

I don't know how to do this easily ?

Answer (score 0):

Try these demos:

[**DEMO 1**](http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/infinite-scrolling-demo5/)

**USAGE HTML:**

```
<ul class="items">
   <li>content</li>
   <li>content</li>
   ...
</ul>
<div id="lastPostsLoader"></div>
```

**USAGE jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function lastAddedLiveFunc()
    {
        $('div#lastPostsLoader').html('<img src="bigLoader.gif">');

        $.get("loadmore.php", function(data){
            if (data != "") {
                //console.log('add data..');
                $(".items").append(data);
            }
            $('div#lastPostsLoader').empty();
        });
    };

    //lastAddedLiveFunc();
    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), winheight =     $(window).height();
        var  scrolltrigger = 0.95;

        if  ((wintop/(docheight-winheight)) > scrolltrigger) {
         //console.log('scroll bottom');
         lastAddedLiveFunc();
        }
    });
});
```

---

[**DEMO 2**](http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/infinite-scrolling-demo2/)

**USAGE HTML:**

```
<div id="postswrapper">
   <div class="item">content</div>
   ...
   <div id="loadmoreajaxloader" style="display:none;"><center><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /></center></div>
</div>
```

**USAGE jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
    {
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
        url: "loadmore.php",
        success: function(html)
        {
            if(html)
            {
                $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
            }else
            {
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.  </center>');
            }
        }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```